# Carbon convert date format

Tags: php, php-carbon

my datepicker sends 'm/d/Y' format
and I need to be 'Y-m-d' format

i tried `Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $request->input('birthdate'));`

still not the result I desire.

Comment: is this issue been resolved ?

Comment: No i end up relying on datepicker formatting

Comment: tried your code .. it's working .. `Carbon::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', '06/21/1990');` assuming second parameter as your $request->bday

Comment: check your data which you are receiving  in `dd($request->input('birthdate'))`